# Trying to get user input shell script programming

Tags: shell, input

I'm trying to make a shell script (.sh) on my mac, but somehow I can't get the 'read' function to work. This is my code:

```
READ -p "What now? " var
ECHO $var
  ECHO " "
  if [ "$var" == "getfiles" ]
   then
    ECHO "Test1"
  elif [ "$var" == "help" ]
   then
    ECHO "Test2"
  else
    ECHO "Please enter a valid command (type 'help' for a list of valid commands)"
  fi
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get user input by using 'READ -p "What now? " var'. However, no matter what I type, it returns an empty variable. I've searched everywhere, but no one seems to have the same problem as I do. I checked the code a thousand times, but can't find any irregularities. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lowercase `read` and `echo`.
`echo "${var}"`is better than `echo $var`